# Struggling with a C++ assignment using the queue and list STL's. Having trouble filling data into a list or queue then printing that data

Tags: c++

I'm working on this project for my CS 22: Introduction to data structures class in c++ . My previous class was in Java, so I'm a lot less comfortable with C+

## Heading

+, and of course, a lot of this stuff is new to me. I'm also in the online class so most of the help I get is from youtube videos and the textbook. Anyway, the assignment is relatively simple, I'm given a program that takes a text file displaying names and GPA's, this file prints out the highest GPA of all of them, and then displays the names of the people with that highest GPA. this is the contents of the text file

3.4 Randy
3.2 Kathy
2.5 Colt
3.4 Tom
3.8 Ron
3.8 Mickey
3.6 Peter
3.5 Donald
3.8 Cindy
3.7 Dome
3.9 Andy
3.8 Fox
3.9 Minnie
2.7 Gilda
3.9 Vinay
3.4 Danny

and this is the original project

```
int main()
{
    //Step 1
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    stackType<string> stack(100);

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          //Step 2

    if (!infile)                                //Step 3
    {
        cout << "The input file does not "
        << "exist. Program terminates!"
        << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint;                 //Step 4
    cout << setprecision(2);                    //Step 4

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      //Step 5

    highestGPA = GPA;                           //Step 6

    while (infile)                              //Step 7
    {
        if (GPA > highestGPA)                   //Step 7.1
        {
            stack.initializeStack();            //Step 7.1.1

            if (!stack.isFullStack())           //Step 7.1.2
                stack.push(name);

            highestGPA = GPA;                   //Step 7.1.3
        }
        else if (GPA == highestGPA)             //Step 7.2
            if (!stack.isFullStack())
                stack.push(name);
            else
            {
                cout << "Stack overflows. "
                << "Program terminates!"
                << endl;
                return 1;  //exit program
            }
        infile >> GPA >> name;                  //Step 7.3
    }

    cout << "Highest GPA = " << highestGPA
    << endl;                               //Step 8
    cout << "The students holding the "
    << "highest GPA are:" << endl;

    while (!stack.isEmptyStack())               //Step 9
    {
        cout << stack.top() << endl;
        stack.pop();
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So the original project is written using a stack implementation my teacher uses from our textbook. And then i'm supposed to rebuild the project using the list STL and the queue STL. I started with queues and this is what I have so far.

```
int main()
{
    //Step 1
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    queue<string> GPAStudents;
//    stackType<string> stack(100);

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          //Step 2

    if (!infile)                                //Step 3
    {
        cout << "The input file does not "
        << "exist. Program terminates!"
        << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint;                 //Step 4
    cout << setprecision(2);                    //Step 4

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      //Step 5

    highestGPA = GPA;                           //Step 6

    GPAStudents.push(name);

    infile >> GPA >> name;
    while (infile)                              //Step 7
    {
        if (GPA > highestGPA)                   //Step 7.1
        {
            //stack.initializeStack();
            //So these two lines of code are supposed to function kinda like intilalizeStack(),
            //whereby initializeStack() sets the stackTop to 0 making empty, this just creates an
            //empty queue and replaces it with our queue
            queue<string> empty;
            swap( GPAStudents, empty );

            if ((GPAStudents.size() < 100))//I did this, cause the original code was checking whether or not the stack was full, and the
                 GPAStudents.push(name);  //original stack was set at 100 so i thought this would work. I hoped it would have the same effect
                                        //as !stack.isFullStack but I guess it doesn't
                highestGPA = GPA;                   //Step 7.1.3
        }
        else if (GPA == highestGPA)             //Step 7.2
            if ((GPAStudents.size() < 100))
                GPAStudents.push(name);
            else
            {
                cout << "Stack overflows. "
                << "Program terminates!"
                << endl;
                return 1;  //exit program
            }
        infile >> GPA >> name;                  //Step 7.3
    }

    cout << "Highest GPA = " << highestGPA
    << endl;                               //Step 8
    cout << "The students holding the "
    << "highest GPA are:" << endl;

    while ((GPAStudents.size() < 100))               //Step 9
    {
        cout << GPAStudents.front() << endl;
        GPAStudents.pop();
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Really I just don't even know where to start. If I had to narrow it down to a single question, how do I get the info from my "highestGPAData.txt" file, containing the GPA's and names, into a list and a queue, from there, I know I could just figure out a way to compare them and check for all the highest and print those, I've been trying to just plug in the queue stl stuff into the orginal code but I know thats not working, I just need help getting started with putting the GPA and names into lists and queues, cause I am confused on how to get that info from the text file into a queue or a list

The final output from the original project and what the final project should look like is this

Highest GPA = 3.90
The students holding the highest GPA are:
Vinay
Minnie
Andy

Program ended with exit code: 0

So, my main goal is just getting that result from the text file and my code using stl list library and then again with stl queue librarys

Update:
I did some more reading and checked out the answer below and made a fair amount of progress, updated code below

```
    int main()
{
    //Step 1
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    list<string> GPANames(0);
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          //Step 2

    if (!infile)                                //Step 3
    {
        cout << "The input file does not "
        << "exist. Program terminates!"
        << endl;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint;                 //Step 4
    cout << setprecision(2);                    //Step 4

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      //Step 5

    highestGPA = GPA;


    while (infile){
        if (GPA > highestGPA)
        {
            GPANames.push_front(name);

            highestGPA = GPA;

        } else if (GPA == highestGPA)
            GPANames.push_front(name);

        infile >> GPA >> name;
    }

    cout << "Highest GPA = " << highestGPA << endl;

    cout << "The students holding the highest GPA are:" << endl;

    while (!GPANames.empty()){
        cout << GPANames.front() << endl;
        GPANames.pop_front();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now my output looks a bit more like its supposed to. It's printing

```
Highest GPA = 3.90
The students holding the highest GPA are:
Vinay
Minnie
Andy
Cindy
Mickey
Ron
Tom
Randy
```

So that's kinda right. The first 3 names are correct, but then it prints like half of the rest of the names so I'm not sure why that is.

Update 2! I added this line

```
GPANames.clear();
```

in here, where the orginal stack initilization was, and now it works.

if (GPA > highestGPA)

```
{
    GPANames.clear();
    GPANames.push_front(name);

    highestGPA = GPA;

} else if (GPA == highestGPA)
    GPANames.push_front(name);

infile >> GPA >> name;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for your first question I highly suggest looking at the [ifstream docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and really c++ streams in general. If you are familiar with Java streams the high level concept is the same but C++ has it's own nuances.

For one, the way that the original project does it is by this line

```cpp
infile >> GPA >> name;
```

if you look at the types of both `GPA` and `name` then you will see why this does what it does. Essentially, this line tries to first find a double in the stream and places it in `GPA` (since `GPA` is a double) then it tries to find the next [white-space separated](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/) string, which is why your data file only has the first name.

Next is the issue of STL lists. Once again if you are familiar with Java Lists the procedure for declaring/managing them is [quite similar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

For example to declare a list that stores integers then you would use the line:

```cpp
#include <list>

int main(){
    std::list<int> numbers;
}
```

Then as you have probably found from your class a stack is FILO which means that you usually push and pop from the same place. We can arbitrarily choose `front` in an STL list. So then in order to add an integer we have:

```cpp
#include <list>

int main(){
    std::list<int> numbers;

    numbers.push_front(1); // {1}
    numbers.push_front(2); // {2, 1}
    numbers.push_front(3); // {3, 2, 1}

    int num;

    num = numbers.front(); // 3
    numbers.pop_front(); // {2, 1}
    num = numbers.front(); // 2
    numbers.pop_front(); // {1}
    num = numbers.front(); // 1
    number.pop_front(); // {}

}
```

In a queue the behaviour is FIFO so you would pop and push in opposite places.

Also one key thing to remember is that the `front()` and `back()` functions return [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) which have some of their own quirks but should honestly not matter for this project.

Hope this helps.

---

#### EDIT

Also, just in case. You probably didn't mean this line:

```cpp
list<string> empty;
swap( GPAStudents, empty );
```

the reason is because even though you declare the `empty` list in the for loop, once it loops the container is still the same list. That is to say:

```
loop iteration 1 start:
empty -> []
GPAStudents -> [somenames]

loop iteration 1 end:
empty -> [somenames]
GPAStudents -> []
```

but when you come back around...

```
loop iteration 2 start:
empty -> [somenames]
GPAStudents -> []

loop iteration 2 end:
empty -> []
GPAStudents -> [somenames]
```

To empty the list use `somelist.clear()`

Comment: That somelist.clear() definitely helped! Now I just have to complete the queue version of the assignment and I'll be done! Thanks for the help! I'm still gonna leave the post up until I finish, but I think I should be able to figure it out from here

Answer (score 0):

Got them both done! Turned out to be a lot more simple than I thought it would be. I've posted my STL list solution and the STL queue solution below! Thanks a bunch for the help ElectrumHafnium.

STL List

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Step 1
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    list<string> GPANames(0);
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          //Step 2

    if (!infile)                                //Step 3
    {
        cout << "The input file does not "
        << "exist. Program terminates!"
        << endl;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint;                 //Step 4
    cout << setprecision(2);                    //Step 4

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      //Step 5

    highestGPA = GPA;


    while (infile){
        if (GPA > highestGPA)
        {
            GPANames.clear();
            GPANames.push_front(name);

            highestGPA = GPA;

        } else if (GPA == highestGPA)
            GPANames.push_front(name);

        infile >> GPA >> name;
    }

    cout << "Highest GPA = " << highestGPA << endl;

    cout << "The students holding the highest GPA are:" << endl;

    while (!GPANames.empty()){
        cout << GPANames.front() << endl;
        GPANames.pop_front();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and then STL Queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Step 1
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    queue <string> GPANames;
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          //Step 2

    if (!infile)                                //Step 3
    {
        cout << "The input file does not "
        << "exist. Program terminates!"
        << endl;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint;                 //Step 4
    cout << setprecision(2);                    //Step 4

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      //Step 5

    highestGPA = GPA;


    while (infile){
        if (GPA > highestGPA)
        {
            queue<string> empty;
            swap(GPANames, empty);

            GPANames.push(name);

            highestGPA = GPA;

        } else if (GPA == highestGPA)
            GPANames.push(name);

        infile >> GPA >> name;
    }

    cout << "Highest GPA = " << highestGPA << endl;

    cout << "The students holding the highest GPA are:" << endl;

    while (!GPANames.empty()){
        cout << GPANames.front() << endl;
        GPANames.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```